Hierarchical models where the hierarchy structure depends on a latent variable
I am having trouble formulating a hierarchical model for the purpose of Bayesian inference in the case where the actual hierarchical structure depends on a latent variable. I am wondering if this is even possible. Here is an example.
I have some observed variables $\theta$ which depend on four latent variables $m$, $z_1$, $z_2$, and $z_3$. These first variable is distributed as $m \sim {\rm DiscreteUniform}(3)$ (Not sure of the standard notation here but what I mean is that $P(m=1) = P(m=2) = P(m=3) = 1/3$) You can think of $m$ as a RV that determines which of the $z_i$ is the "maximum" in the following sense:
If $m=1$, then
$$
\begin{align}
z_1 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1) \\
z_2 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_1) \\
z_3 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_2)
\end{align}
$$
If $m=2$, then
$$
\begin{align}
z_2 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1) \\
z_1 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_2) \\
z_3 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_2)
\end{align}
$$
If $m=3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
z_3 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1) \\
z_2 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_3) \\
z_1 &\sim {\rm Uniform}(0, z_2)
\end{align}
$$
The idea here is that one of the $z_i$ should have a maximum value, and no $z_i$ can be larger than the adjacent one (this is the feature I am after with this whole construction). These $z_i$ go on to determine my observed variables in a way unimportant for the current question, I think.
Is there a way to formulate this as a proper hierarchical model, with different "branches" depending on the value of $m$? Or is this really a problem of Bayesian model selection between competing hierarchical models? I would appreciate any insights or resource recommendations in either case. Thank you.

Do you have indicators of these latent variables or is it purely hypothetical/theoretical? Most applications of latent variable models I've used (admittedly only a subset involving random effects regression and structural equation models) require a set of measured variables that help one infer the random variable.

Purely theoretical unfortunately. I basically am just after a way to draw the $z_i$ such that, when considered as an ordered set, there is there is a single local extremum, but I don't want to assume too much else about their correlations.

Gotcha. I am not sure how to build this into a model. Sorry I can't be of more help!
